# How to build a website from ASCIIDoc-files?

Tags: html, converters, asciidoc

Is there an easy way to generate a website with menue,... from ASCIIDoc-files?

Let's say I have a couple of ASCII-Doc files:

```
chapter-1.asciidoc
chapter-2.asciidoc
chapter-3.asciidoc
chapter-4.asciidoc
```

I also have a Website Skeleton, that contains everything but the "main content" of a file

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="chapter-1.asciidoc">
<a href="chapter-2.asciidoc">
<a href="chapter-3.asciidoc">
<a href="chapter-4.asciidoc">

CONTENT SHOULD GO HERE

</body>
</html>
```

Now I'd like to generate 4 html-files, that have the rendered HTML-Commands, which is placed into the copy of the website Skeleton (here replacing the 
`CONTENT SHOULD GO HERE`)

Is there a tool that allows something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use something like Middleman, awestruct, jekyll or the like. Neither Asciidoc (the python impl) nor Asciidoctor (the ruby or javascript impls or java wrapper AsciidoctorJ) can do this out of the box. Another way to do this would be to use one of the aforementioned implementations and call the API to render the asciidoc document then spit out the rendered content.